# Verbal offer of employment, letter of confirmation with offer not sent, due to start work Monday next

Tags: interviewing

Last week Monday I got a call from a company I recently interviewed with and I was told that the position was offered to me. The person who called told me that they would be sending me a letter of acceptance/confirmation letter with the company's offer (i.e. financial offer, working hours, etc.)  in a day or two via email, however nothing came as of this posting (today being Saturday) and now I am concerned because I am due to start work on Monday coming and I am not sure what the offer is going to be like, there is no room for negotiation on my part. My question is what to do with only hours before I am due to start?

Comment: If they told you on Monday that they'll send you the offer within 1 or 2 days, then why, when you saw on Friday that it didn't happen, didn't you call them or email them ? Maybe they sent it, but it got blocked by some spam filter, or they have a new employee in HR who was suppose to handle this and they screwed up somehow... Always always contact them if you're in such a situation, to re-establish communication and kill the awkward silence...

Comment: It's Monday. Any updates? We are all curious.

Comment: Worth noting: http://thedailywtf.com/Comments/Jumping-the-Resignagun.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If nothing's been signed, technically, [the good news] *you're still negotiating*. Also, technically, [the bad news] *you're not yet employed on monday*. Odds are good that they're not actually going to be ready to have you start work when you show up.

Your best option is to **go in**. plan to only stay for 2 hours, and only **achieve two goals**: **get a written offer** from them, and **get time to think about it**.

---

Psyche yourself up. This is your plan. You go in, go to the front desk, say it's your first day, find the person that hired you, explain the situation, and ask to see the contract/offer letter. Take the offer/contract letter, tell them you need a few days to think about it, and walk out. Do all this while being very nice, and very reasonable - explain that you like the company, want to work for them, but also this is a big decision for you, and you take big decisions slowly. Ask them who you should speak with if you have questions about the offer - and make sure you're walking out with that contact information in hand.

**Once you're home, you'll read the offer, and decide how to proceed**. Plan specifically on not making any decisions while at the company.

---

*Caveat:* do a quick scan of the offer when it's handed to you. If it looks ridiculously out of the ballpark, react appropriately - if it's too low, hand the offer back. If it's too high, sign it on the spot. MAKE SURE YOU READ THE ENTIRE DOCUMENT, TWICE, BEFORE SIGNING. TAKE YOUR TIME.

*Caveat 2:* if you're desperate for a job (ie, life or death or equivalent situation), just take it. better to risk being taken advantage of than not to have the job. otherwise, understand that you're risking not-accepting-a-shitty-job. there is a good chance this is just a screw up, in which case, everyone will be understanding and let you have time and space. there is a very small chance that you're dealing with someone, along the lines of communication, that is trying to take advantage of you. this stance will make sure they can't - and they might decide not to hire someone, who they can't take advantage of.

---

**NOTE** that this kind of screw up, while not common, is not that infrequent - I've personally experienced it with very large, very well known, companies... Imagine that you're dealing with a new manager, who doesn't quite know the mechanisms for handling hr, etc... Always, it's very embarrassing for the company, and they will go out of their way to correct, and make sure you're happy.

**Note 2**: i'm assuming that you didn't accept the verbal offer. Be aware that a promise-to-mail-an-offer is not an actual offer - an actual offer would be more like: "Your salary is x, your hours are y, are you interested?" and your response is something along the lines of "Yes" or "No".

Answer (score 5):

You are in a bad position because you will go there on Monday morning, and you won't have been able to think about their offer even over the weekend. On the other hand, you are in a good position because on Monday morning, they want you to start but because of their own fault, you haven't been able to read their offer, and if it isn't acceptable to you they have to do something right there.

Take the weekend to prepare yourself mentally for some negotiations. Decide what you will try to get, and at what point you won't accept what they offer. Keep in mind that I would want to hire someone who is confident and knows what she or he is worth. And that a company gains much more by hiring someone who is good and gets things done, than by saving a little bit in the employment contract. Do some searches on stack exchange and other sites for articles about it, and there is plenty of helpful information out there. Go to bed early on Sunday, no heavy drinking, so you are in the best possible condition on Monday morning.

Your assumption that there is no room for negotiation is just wrong. It's not your fault that the email wasn't sent. And remember that all the skills you show to get the best job conditions for yourself will be helping the company for years to come and make you more valuable.

Comment: You're right. A lot of times they'll tell you it's not negotiable, but an offer is always negotiable when it comes to such a job.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I'm a strong believer in saying "Nothing is nonnegotiable" (in all walks of life)

Answer (score 3):

If you still want the job, I would simply show up at work, and take it from there. If the company is somewhat bigger, just go to the reception and say this is your first day. They will probably ask for a contact, you can give the name of the person that made you the offer in the first place.

In terms of negotiation room, I don't see any differences. You have not signed a contract yet, so there is still room to talk about the contents of the contract. You can also still leave if the offer is not good enough for you.

Comment: Don't assume they did not send the mail, inquire politely. The email may have been caught by any of the spam filters along the way, they may have mistyped your email address, ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you know specifically at what time you're supposed to show up on Monday, at what desk and who is supposed to greet you? Hint:

1. you may still have forms such as your tax forms to fill out and the greeter is supposed to give you these forms.
2. In addition, the greeter should help you with your user login and your company email account let alone orient you as to which way is the bathroom, the coffee machine and the cafeteria and introduce you to your coworkers and management as well as how to get in touch with them.
3. Finally, the greeter should be available to answer any questions or respond to any request you may have during the course of your first workday.

That's why you just can't show up unannounced and uninvited on the first day.

If you don't have the answer to these three questions, stay home. Email, phone - do whatever it takes until you get the answers you need. Explain the urgency of the situation and your awkwardness being in the situation. When you have the answers and only then, show up.

You can negotiate your compensation once the official offer is on the table i.e. you have received the offer with a number printed on it.