# Verbal Confirmation but long wait?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I've been interviewing for a job , and had successfully cleared their interviews!

After a week, the company emailed me that I was accepted for the job. 
I was really delighted to hear that.They told me that the paper work for approval needs time and they hoped I'll be patient with them.

After another 2 weeks, they told me that the paper work had been all done, and I just need to wait for the HR to call me up for the signing of contract by that week.

So I waited.

After that week , I didn't received any calls from them, so I emailed the HR. 
They replied , asking me to wait and reassured me that my position has been confirmed and by end of the week they will get back to me.

And I waited with no calls/emails that week. Again, I emailed them. Again, they assured me that my position is Confirmed and by the end of the week they'll get back to me.

So, I'm waiting for a month or so now. And just recently,I emailed them again. But they didn't reply at all.

They keep assuring that my position is confirmed, and so I'm very troubled and should I be concerned about this long wait ?

Thanks!

Comment: @Dawny33 The title is related but the circumstances are sufficiently different: this OP was offered the job, the other OP wasn't and it's (regrettably) common for employers to not even get back to candidates, though that's more rare for finalists.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks for pointing out. Even [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28189/verbal-offer-of-employment-letter-of-confirmation-with-offer-not-sent-due-to-s?rq=1) question also looks similar, but not the same.

Comment: @Dawny33 Yes there are quite a few on this theme, but nothing that really answers the general question.

Answer (score 2):

There can be all sorts of reasons for delays in the recruitment process, most of them are not visible to the candidate as they are internal process and procedural delays and many of them should not be viewed negatively, worrisome though delays can be at this stage. However I would be very nervous if I haven't received any paperwork three weeks after being accepted for the position.

It is likely there are "good" reasons for this internally (perhaps the right person is away ill, or there have been unforeseen higher priorities for the HR department or any number of other things).

But, if they have stopped answering your emails and they are taking this long to get an offer letter out (a basic HR function and process, it should not be a problem) then to me that red-flags the company, particularly if they appear to have no appreciation of the worry they are putting you through. It might be alright in the end, but is this the kind of company you want to work for?

If it were me I would regretfully begin looking for work again, without necessarily saying anything to the original company. Write it off in your mind, leave them alone, and get on with looking for a company that likes you so much they pull out all the stops to get you on board. Then if the original company comes back to you in their own good time then you can consider what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

> should I be concerned about this long wait ?

Yes, and do not stop job hunting. A month is far beyond a reasonable wait, and the fact that they are not replying to your emails makes it even more suspicious.

So best to keep looking for a job and assume that this one is not going to happen. Possibly you will be contacted soon and get a written confirmation, but chances are you will not.